# NLTK CorpusTerm by Document matrix

Tags: python, text, nltk, lsa

I am going to use CountVectorizer with a large corpus which I retrieve from Gutenberg (or any dat set from nltk)
There are ebooks in tis corpus. I want to gather all sentences in those books in the same list. Something like that:
listsentences=["SENTENCE#1" ,"SENTENCE#2" ,"SENTENCE#3" ...]
I am stuck how to create sentence list. 
Any help is massively appreciated!
This is how my code looks like:

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
text=nltk.corpus.gutenberg.fileids()
gutenberg.fileids()
emma=gutenberg.sents()
vectorizer=CountVectorizer(min_df = 1, stop_words = 'english')
dtm= vectorizer.fit_transform(emma)
pd.DataFrame(dtm.toarray(),columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names()).head(10)
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
lsa = TruncatedSVD(3, algorithm = 'arpack')
dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm)
dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
```

Comment: What kind of sentence list were you expecting? Sentences don't repeat like words, so you won't be getting a frequency count. There is a POS (Parts of speech) analysis built into the NLTK.

Comment: Thank you for your response Mike! I am running LSA, so eventually I would like to get term by document (or sentence)matrix. I used very small dataset o CountVectorizer and run TruncatedSVD. The dat set was a list of sentences, so I want to create the same format of nltk corpus texts.

Comment: Try modifying your question and add a little table illustrating what you want to get out of the NLTK. That will help people find you an answer.

Comment: Don't you already have all sentences in gutenberg.sents() ?

Comment: Your variable `emma` contains all sentences from the gutenberg corpus. You're getting your examples mixed up.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses. I greatly appreciated. emma has the sentences but not the format I want. For instance this is emma[24]:      [u'She',u'dearly', u'loved'] but I would like to have ['She dearly loved']